# Replacing a character with a space and dividing the string into two words in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe that contains a column that includes strings separeted with semi-colons and it is followed by a space. But unfortunately in some of the strings there is a semi-colon that is not followed by a space.

In this case, This is what i'd like to do: If there is a space after the semi-colon we do not need a change. However if there are letters before and after the semi-colon, we should change semi-colon with space

i have this:

```
        datacolumn1
 row 1  knowledge; information; data
 row 2  digital;transmission; interoperability; data labeling
 row 3  library catalogs; libraries; mobile;libraries
```

I need this output:

```
       datacolumn1
row 1  knowledge; information; data
row 2  digital transmission; interoperability; data labeling
row 3  library catalogs; libraries; mobile libraries
```

Comment: You're going to need to clearly explain the replacement logic.  I don't see any obvious pattern or rules here.

Comment: How'd R know which semi-colon to remove? In row2, the semi-colon between "digital" and "transmission" is removed, same as in row3 ?

Comment: Ok, let's look at the row two. There is a couple of word (digital transmission) but it was written as digital;transmission. Similarly in row3 the mobile libraries written as mobile;libraries. We'd like to change the ; signs with spaces in these words.

Comment: If there is a space after the semi-colon we do not need a change. However if there are letters before or after the semi-colon, we should change semi-colon with space

Comment: @caniero So, why you remove 'data' from the first row

Comment: @RaviSaroch. That's my mistake, sorry. Now, it is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(datacolumn1, "(\\w);(\\w)", "\\1 \\2")
```

This is probably a neater regex out there, but this will do!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex to select ";" not leaded or followed by space then replace it with space :

```
(?<!\s);(?!\s)
```

> (?<!\s) : negative lookbehind to check if not leaded by space or \n or \t
> (?!\s) : negative lookahead to check if not followed by space or \n or \t

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qytLB2/2/)